# Why isn't there a procedure for dual-engine failure in twin-engine airplanes?

Tags: faa-regulations, general-aviation, usa, engine-failure, multi-engine

I'm licensed to fly multi-engine aircraft. I currently fly the [DA-42NG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_DA42).

However, nowhere in my training and in the official POH was I introduced to procedures for handing a dual-engine failure in-flight.

There's no mention of a Best Glide Speed whatsoever.

I'm assuming this is the case for most, or maybe all GA Twin-Engine airplanes. I know jets can glide for some time without any power.

Question is - can GA airplanes? I know it won't fall like a rock - but there's got to be some science to follow here, right? Why haven't the manufactures mentioned it even once? Why isn't it part of the training?

Comment: Usually for light singles, glide speed is pretty much the same as approach speed, which is 1.3 * VSO. I can't imagine with feathered props that this rule would be much different in twins, so if you have a dual failure scenario I'd stick to normal approach speed as your glide speed. The other advantage is you should be very familiar with that descent rate and distance.

Comment: My opinion on the subject is that the powers that be, over aviation, evolved from a single-engine transitioning to multi-engine mindset, and therefore, it is ingrained in the training culture that anyone who is earning a multi-engine rating posesses a single-engine rating, and that, in the case of all engines failing in a multi-engine airplane, they would utilize the training for an engine failure in a single-engine airplane.  Due to that, multi-engine curriculum exclude this.

Comment: I can't understand why there is already a close vote on that question. If the voter could explain...

Comment: @RyanMortensen Granted that is true, the aircraft manual should still list a best glide speed.

Comment: I wonder if maybe it's a safety issue to list a best glide speed.  What if both engines fail, someone goes to best glide below Vmca and then for some reason, an engine restarts and puts the plane in a spin.  That's probably not the reason, but then again... lawyers.

Comment: I'm guessing that it must be certification requirements.  Transport category aircraft (at least all of the two and three engine models that I have flown) DO have an "all engines out" emergency checklist procedure.

Comment: The best endurance glide speed is (for all aircraft) the same (or nearly so; the propeller drag might make a small difference) as the best rate of climb speed. Best distance glide speed is a bit higher (while best angle of climb is a bit lower).

Comment: @RyanMortensen I'm not sure I fully agree. While we of course hold a single-engine certificate before getting a multi-engine rating, how we handle engine failures in single engine vs multi-engine is not exactly the same. Regardless - it is unlikely that the licensing authority would simply want pilots to "do what you learnt when flying the SE aircraft".

Comment: @RaajTram well for one thing, there is no rule, at least not in the U.S., that says you can't be multi-engine rated without being single-engine rated, but I have yet to meet anyone who only has M.E..  I'm not asserting anything with certainty here, which is why I haven't posted an answer, just comments.  Manufacturers may exclude it because going below Vmca (down to best glide) is considered dangerous in case one engine restarts itself (**just a guess**).  I don't see how procedures for a multi-engine-all-failed, scenario would be much different than the procedures in a single-engine.

Comment: Have you read all the manuals? Jets usually have table somewhere for speed to fly without engines. Anyway the speed will be near the best rate of climb speed. On Airbus 320 is green dot speed.

Answer (score 11):

There are.  The Metroliner (SA227) has a dual flameout checklist.  It's possible that the company I flew for developed their own and had it approved, but we DID have a checklist for that.

I think they're rare on pistons twins because there are a very limited number of environmental factors that can cause double engine failures.  It's also possible to simply run out of gas.*  A turbine can ingest water, ice, dust, sand, snow, etc (no filters) that can contribute to a flameout.  The factor that causes one to quit will likely effect the other in a similar way.

I do know a pilot who flamed out both engines by using engine inlet heat on both engines at the same time.  The ice melted off the inlets at about the same time, both engines ingested the ice, and they quit.  He managed to relight both of them and landed uneventfully.  That likely would not happen in a piston twin.  The alt air doors would open and keep the engines running.

*If you find yourself thinking "I'm going to need that double engine failure checklist in about 20mins," you should probably seriously reflect upon the decisions you made throughout the flight.

Comment: Fuel starvation is pretty common in GA and would certainly effect both engines.

Comment: Right, but that is generally a pilot controlled problem. My understanding is that the double engine failure checklist is there to cover unforeseen external causes of engine failures. I can't explain how I got that idea into my head...must have been part of some training along the way. I agree with you though, running out of gas another reason for a double engine failure.

Comment: Yeah, but Greg is right.  Engine failures due to pilot error are still engine failures, and we should expect procedures to exist,.

Comment: I can't argue with that.

Comment: @acpilot expecting an engine failure (dual or single) vs experiencing an engine failure all of a sudden are two completely different scenarios. The former is undoubtedly the pilot's fault, but not the latter. My original question is related to the latter situation.

Comment: It still cold be the pilot's fault.  See engine ice example in the answer.  I can think of few instances of sudden double engie failure in which the pilot would not be somehow responsible.

Answer (score 1):

Training is done to the extent that there are procedures to follow for a particular failure.

There are checklists for restarting engines during a dual engine failure, but the checklists don't include what to do if they can't manage to restart to engine.

They must use their knowledge and piloting skills to glide to a nearby airport.