# What is the A320's procedure for dual engine failure at very low altitude?

Tags: airbus-a320, engine-failure, emergency-procedures

What is the procedure for a dual engine failure in an Airbus A320 (perhaps a large bird strike, since these engines only tolerate medium birds) at a very low altitude, shortly after takeoff (approx 1,000 ft)? Additionally, will *any* procedure realistically save an aircraft in such a scenario?

Comment: One of the recommendations of the Hudson bay ditching was that there should be a specific checklist for low-altitude dual engine failure that focuses more on flying rather than troubleshooting. I'm curious to see if that's already been made.

Comment: @Sanchises Indeed interesting, however the Hudson Bay occurred at a much more forgiving altitude (I think they reached around 3,000 ft).

Comment: No procedure would save the aircraft at 1000ft, but the terrain might.

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/28002/62)

Comment: @Sanchises: Hudson Bay ditching?  I don't recall any Airbus being ditched in Hudson Bay - which is in northern Canada.  You may be thinking of the Hudson RIVER, which is a good ways further south :-)  And connected only by both having been discovered by and named for Henry Hudson: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Hudson

Comment: @jamesqf Uh oh, imperialist American spotted ;)

Comment: @jamesqf It was a government cover-up. Ditching in the Hudson Bay wasn't quite as impressive so they transported an A320 (actually a repainted B737) to the Hundson river by barge. Alternatively, I didn't pay attention when writing that comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every pilot is taught that in an emergency you fly the plane first and everything else is secondary. Aviate, then communicate. At 1,000 ft there's not going to be much you can do other than figure out how to try to get back down in as few pieces as possible. If you have done your pre-flight planning correctly, long before you line up on the runway you have already thought of what you will do if you find yourself in such a scenario, and discussed it with your FO so you are both on the same page.

Comment: ... assuming I‘m not the FO! Good answer though.